# Batch function arguments and iteration inside of a function

Tags: batch-file

I have a Batch file with a function definition at the end. I know for a fact the function is the problem, because the error returns when it reaches any call to the function or the definition itself. I receive the error: `the syntax of the command is incorrect.` I've checked the nests of parentheses for errors but to no avail. Does Batch permit me to request `if defined` statements toward arguments and call a function inside of itself?

Other than that, I can't seem to work out the error.

```
rem Functions.
:checkLvl
if "%~1" EQU "%~2" (
    set counter=0
    if defined %~3 echo %~3
    if defined %~4 echo 1: %~4 &&set counter=1
    if defined %~5 echo 2: %~5 &&set counter=2
    if defined %~6 echo 3: %~6 &&set counter=3
    if defined %~7 echo 4: %~7 &&set counter=4
    if defined %~4 ( 
        set /p checkChoice=
        if defined !checkChoice! ( 
            if !checkChoice! GTR 0 ( 
                if !checkChoice! LEQ !counter! ( 
                    set checkChoice=!checkChoice!
                ) else (
                    echo Enter a value below or equal to !counter! and greater than 0.
                    set checkChoice=null
                    call:checkLvl %~1 %~2 %~3 %~4 %~5 %~6 %~7
                ) 
            ) else (
                echo Enter a proper value.
                set checkChoice=null
                call:checkLvl %~1 %~2 %~3 %~4 %~5 %~6 %~7
            ) 
        ) else (
            echo Enter a value (1-!counter!).
            set checkChoice=null
            call:checkLvl %~1 %~2 %~3 %~4 %~5 %~6 %~7
        )
    )
    set returnCheck=true
) else ( set returnCheck=false )
goto:eof
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this function?  Knowing your goal will help us understand your code.  Also are you passing in variable names for the parameters?  Reason I ask is because the `defined` command can only check if a variable is defined, not a parameter.

Comment: @DavidRuhmann The goal is to check if any variable provided is equal to another provided, and thus echo any variables after that, then have the user select one of the choices given from the echoes.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use DEFINED with batch parameters and for loop variables. Use `if "%~1"==""` .